# PyYAML - Skipping certain keys when dumping a dict to file

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have a YAML file with configuration data for my application, which is dumped to a new file whenever the application is run for debugging purposes. Unfortunately, some keys in the YAML file hold sensitive data and need to be obfuscated or simply excluded from the dumped file.

Example YAML input file:

```
logging_config:
    level: INFO
    file_path: /path/to/log_file.log
database_access:
    table_to_query: customer_table
    database_api_key: XXX-XXX-XXX  # Sensitive data, exclude from archived file
```

There are workarounds, of course:

- Keeping a list of keys with sensitive data and pre-processing dicts before outputting them to YAML
- Separating sensitive and non-sensitive data in separate configuration files and outputtiing only the latter
- etc.

But I was hoping that there was a solution similar to implementing a custom `Loader` reacting to a command like `!keep_secret` whenever it appears in a dict value, as it would keep my configuration files more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom representer. Here's a basic example:

```py
import yaml

class SensitiveText:
  def __init__(self, content):
    self.content = content

  def __repr__(self):
    return self.content

  def __str__(self):
    return self.content

def sensitive_text_remover(dumper, data):
  return dumper.represent_scalar("tag:yaml.org,2002:null", "")

yaml.add_representer(SensitiveText, sensitive_text_remover)

data = {
  "logging_config": {
    "level": "INFO", 
    "file_path": "/path/to/log_file.log"
  },
  "database_access": {
    "table_to_query": "customer_table",
    "database_api_key": SensitiveText("XXX-XXX-XXX")
  }
}

print(yaml.dump(data))
```

This prints:

```
database_access:
  database_api_key:
  table_to_query: customer_table
logging_config:
  file_path: /path/to/log_file.log
  level: INFO
```

You can of course have a class for the `database_access` instead with a representer that removes the `database_api_key` altogether.